# Update an existing value in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add to an existing value in Firebase
I have an updatePoints function that looks up a user, if they already exist I want to lookup up the existing points and add the newPoints value. How can I do this with the below please?

```
updatePoints(userID, newPoints){
firebase.database().ref('/userProfile').child(userID).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);

  if (exists) {
      console.log('user ' + userID + ' exists!');

        firebase.database().ref('markets/'+userID).update({ 
        points: newPoints  // I want to look up eixsitg points and add on newPoints,

      });

    } else {
      console.log('user ' + userID + ' does not exist!');
      firebase.database().ref('/markets').child(userID).set({ 
      points: 1

      });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, if this helps someone...

```
console.log("val",snapshot.val().points);
```